# Sphere equipping strategies

Tags: brave-frontier

What strategies are there to consider when equipping a unit with spheres?  Using generic stat increasing spheres like Giants Shield for example, is it best to equip it to a unit with naturally high defense for a greater start gain?  Or should I use it on a lower defense unit to supplement their weakness?

Is there another strategy to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commonly use defense, recovery and resistance spheres for units that are needing it. I use attack spheres on units that already have a high attack for overkilling cause it is very important when participating in events, arena and special vortex dungeons. Spheres like Muramasa, Zeus Bow, etc. are best equipped for certain units. When in quest dungeons, always use attack spheres on units that will deal great damage for that dungeon. Rest would be defense spheres, resistance spheres, etc. ;)